# How to get Outlook 2003 accounts list using Outlook 2003 object model

Tags: c#, com, outlook-2003

Is it possible to get list of all existing accounts from Outlook 2003 using only standard COM? 
It means I can't use Redemption library, but only [default Outlook 2003 object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289167(VS.71).aspx) .
It's much easy to get accounts at Outlook 2007/2010:

```
dynamic outlook = AutomationFactory.GetObject("Outlook.Application");
var accounts = outlook.Session.Accounts;
```

But there is no "Accounts" property for Outlook 2003. By default I can access only default account using "CurrentUser" property. So maybe is there some another way to obtain all accounts (using ONLY Outlook 2003 object model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally [found answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118211/how-can-i-get-outlook-2003-data-in-silverlight-4-application/3189975#3189975). I'm not using object model, but I do exactly same as Redemption (read registry). So it's acceptable answer as for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Accounts property is not available in the Outlook 2003 object model. One way to get this information is to use [Extended MAPI](https://web.archive.org/web/20120213055422/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/aa294491%28v=office.11%29.aspx) (MAPI 1.0), and the [EnumerateAccounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa192865%28v=office.11%29) method of the [IOlkAccountManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa203900%28v=office.11%29) interface. However, using Extendend MAPI from manage code is [discouraged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mstehle/fyi-why-are-mapi-and-cdo-1-21-not-supported-in-managed-net-code). There are third party wrappers available, a pouplar one being [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/). Below are a few resources that will be helpful.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200018

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CMapiEx.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/BridgingTheGap.aspx

Comment: I need accounts, not contacts. They're different things.

Comment: I misread your question. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I wrote before, I can't use Redemption library or other third party libs. But I've already found answer. So thanks for your help.