# Outlook Add-in read Server Settings

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, imap, exchange-server

I am searching for a way to read out IMAP/Microsoft Exchange settings from Outlook with an Outlook Add-In coded in c#.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.account_members.aspx) interface of the `Office.Interop.Outlook` dll.

You haven't mentioned what version of Outlook you're using, this code is for Outlook 2010, written by Microsoft MVP Helmut Obertanner, taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff462091%28v=office.14%29.aspx) :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace OutlookAddIn1
{
    class Sample
    {
        public static void DisplayAccountInformation(Outlook.Application application)
        {

            // The Namespace Object (Session) has a collection of accounts.
            Outlook.Accounts accounts = application.Session.Accounts;

            // Concatenate a message with information about all accounts.
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            // Loop over all accounts and print detail account information.
            // All properties of the Account object are read-only.
            foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
            {

                // The DisplayName property represents the friendly name of the account.
                builder.AppendFormat("DisplayName: {0}\n", account.DisplayName);

                // The UserName property provides an account-based context to determine identity.
                builder.AppendFormat("UserName: {0}\n", account.UserName);

                // The SmtpAddress property provides the SMTP address for the account.
                builder.AppendFormat("SmtpAddress: {0}\n", account.SmtpAddress);

                // The AccountType property indicates the type of the account.
                builder.Append("AccountType: ");
                switch (account.AccountType)
                {

                    case Outlook.OlAccountType.olExchange:
                        builder.AppendLine("Exchange");
                        break;

                    case Outlook.OlAccountType.olHttp:
                        builder.AppendLine("Http");
                        break;

                    case Outlook.OlAccountType.olImap:
                        builder.AppendLine("Imap");
                        break;

                    case Outlook.OlAccountType.olOtherAccount:
                        builder.AppendLine("Other");
                        break;

                    case Outlook.OlAccountType.olPop3:
                        builder.AppendLine("Pop3");
                        break;
                }

                builder.AppendLine();
            }

            // Display the account information.
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I can see from the documentation that this should in theory work for Outlook 2007 as well.

If you intend to use Outlook 2003, you're going to have to do things a bit differently as the Outlook 2003 object model did not include access to the Accounts property.

To do it, you'll either have to use a third party library such as redemption for example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3187547/1220971) for some alternatives.

You can apparently also use the Registry to do it as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118211/how-can-i-get-outlook-2003-data-in-silverlight-4-application/3189975#3189975) to another question.

Answer (score 0):

For the exchange settings, you may check this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/exchange